# Laravel 5.6 .ajax post request not received

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Following a simple tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm. (The tutorial was done on a earlier version of Laravel as it's referring to app\http\routes.php.)

```
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script>
     function getMessage(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
           success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
        });
     }
  </script>
```

My function in web.php is not triggered. Click the button, nothing happens.
Debug the .ajax call on the page and the .ajax is triggered.

Put a breakpoint in my web.php, that is not hit:

```
Route::get('ajax',function(){
return view('ajax');
});
Route::post('/getmsg',function(){
$msg = "This is a simple message.";
return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
});
```

Checked the laravel.log and nothing is there.

Is there something wrong with the post request?
Is there anyway to trace Laravel to see where did the request go?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's now working as: moved "Route::post('/getmsg',function()" to routes\api.php. Changed the js url to: url:'/api/getmsg'

Answer (score 1):

All the `API` calls are being hit inside of `api.php` file, not your `web.php`. That being said you need to move your routes from `web.php` to `api.php`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Moved to routes\api.php, still nothing happens.

Comment: It's now working after I updated the js to url:'/api/getmsg'

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that the routes in `api.php` are all prefixed with `/api/` :)

Comment: My route in api.php route::post('/getmsg', 'AjaxController@index'); doesn't work. I have call a function in my route. why? Thank you.

Comment: `route` cannot be lowercase, it must be with a capital letter `R`, so `Route`

Comment: Thank you. That's one problem. Also $this->middleware('auth'); also blocking it. So the JS has bugs too.

Comment: I don't follow you

Comment: My controller has "    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }". So my Ajax request keeps getting 401 back. Even I added _token in data.

Comment: Put the token into the url of the ajax as a get param

Comment: You mean don't use "$this->middleware('auth');"? Manual validate?  url:'/api/getmsg/{{ csrf_token() }}',

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your javascript

```
function getMessage() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/getmsg",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
      if (token) {
        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
      }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#msg").html(data.msg);
      alert(data.msg);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("Error!!!!");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: test:
alert("Error!!!!");
console.debug(data);
check the browser console

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Laravel didn't get the request, or ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @Nikola Gavric's answer, if you are using the controller constructor for calling the middleware method. Like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Then, after relocating your routes from `web.php` to `api.php`, you would need to tell Laravel that you are using **two guards** for your routes. One for the routes in `web.php` and one for `api.php`. To do this, change the code above to this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth:web' || 'auth:api']); 
}
```

Hope this helps future readers of this post. Thanks :)